# Measure of the intersection of measurable sets

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathbb{X},\mu)$ a measurable space such that $\mu (X)=1$. Let $(A_n)\subseteq \mathbb{X}$ with $\mu (A_n)=1, \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$, show that $\mu (\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}})=1$.

I know that $\bigcap(A_n)\subseteq A_n$, so $\mu (\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}}A_n)\leq \mu(A_n)=1$.
But I don't know how to show the other inequality. 
I'll appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: Consider the measure of its complement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the hipotesis it follows $\mu(X\backslash A_n)=0$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, then
\begin{align}
0\le\mu\left(X\backslash\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}}{A_n}\right) & =\mu\left(\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}{X\backslash A_n}\right) \qquad\text{By DeMorgan's Laws} \\
& \le \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\mu(X\backslash A_n)} \\
& = 0.
\end{align}
Then $\mu\left(X\backslash\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}}{A_n}\right)=0$ and $\mu \left(\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}}{A_n}\right)=\mu(X)-\mu\left(X\backslash\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}}{A_n}\right)=1-0=1$.